# "Prior to the 1980s" does it include the 1980s or not?

Tags: prepositions, word-meaning, ambiguity

> High pollution was observed prior to the 1980s.

Which period does 'Prior to the 1980s' refer to, 1)include, 2)partially include, 3)exclude the period of the 1980s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior means 'before'. If something happened prior to the 1980s, it happened before that decade.

> prior to sth
>
> before a particular time or event:
>
> the weeks prior to her death

[Prior (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prior)

Answer (score 1):

"[Prior to](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prior_to#English)" is an exact synonym of "before." So strictly speaking, the phrase "prior to the 1980s" does not include the 1980s.

That said, "the 1980s" is a vague term. It doesn't necessarily mean the precise period from 1 January 1980 to 31 December 1989. The phrase therefore has some inherent gray area and only means that the 1980s were the first decade during which a noticeable change occurred.

Comment: The expression says that high pollution was observed before the 1980s. That's all it says.